# Use of Event cards without corresponding rules

Tags: risk-legacy

The game board reserves a space for Event cards, but how they come into the game is a secret, thus spoiler protection below.

> The "sign the board twice" envelope introduces the Event cards, with rules concerning them to be pasted into the rulebook. I know this from an earlier group. My current group has not yet opened that envelope, but we did just open the "all nine minor cities" envelope, which contains a few event cards like Resistance and Riots. Are we supposed to play with those few event cards now, or set them aside until the rules take effect?

Comment: I have no official answer, but I'd say that if there aren't rules in the rulebook about a component (yet), then you can't use that component (yet). Assume that you hadn't had prior knowledge from a previous game; what would you do with this new category of cards that have no rules associated with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: In fact, the event card rules are printed in the rulebook from the beginning, not revealed in an envelope. I wasn't able to review the rulebook until my group met again to play, but I'm glad that I checked for it there in time to play correctly.